# How to keep at the current Scroll position in ListView.builder without any auto scroll when new items added

Tags: flutter, dart

the use case : i am making pagination in chat page, the reverse set to false , and when user scroll up to load more items the scroll auto jump to 0 offset , How to prevent it ? i want like whatever items added so want to stay at the same current position .

I researched a lot about this problem and the solution scenarios I found like following

- reverse set to true : but this not suite my case because i also have two side pagination too
- Calculate the height difference between before and after items added : but i found this so
  complicated And not always accurate (Any accurate calculation for this thing, please share)

any solution guys with this very annoying behavior?

Comment: I feel like you will have to go with the 2nd option, I think WhatsApp uses the same approach

Comment: 2nd option is more hard than you imagine (if is not impossible) because you get into items that is no longer visible so you no longer able to get their height values

Comment: add a key to your list view

Comment: ``key: PageStorageKey("chatKey"),`` something like this

Comment: @ĐứcThànhLê Thành Lê PageStorageKey this is for preserving scroll while navigate pages and back

Comment: Your listview scroll top top because the ``build`` is called to trigger a rebuild. Add a key to help the list maintain the ``scroll position``. Otherway is to have a variable and attached a ``ScrollController`` to your list view. Listen to scroll position change via listerner and store it in a variable. when finish paging, call ``animate`` method to position store in variable

Comment: for your first way you does not make sense , for the 2nd way we always need the first frame to handle the changed which you gonna have some un accepted scroll

Comment: Share your code about pagination and how you implement your listview

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `key` attribute inside your `ListView.builder` widget. Try skipping that attribute. I was having the same problem and fixed it using this. In this way, it keeps its position when new items are added.

Comment: Can you please explain more of what do you mean of skipping that attribute exactly ? do you mean to remove the global key from list ?